# вопрос по таблицам sql

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня задача

1. Разработать БД для учета продажи товаров в сети магазинов. БД должна содержать следующие сведения: номер, название, адрес магазина, ФИО его руководителя, наименование товара, его вид, единица измерения, стоимость за единицу, дата поступления, дата продажи, количество, общая стоимость, общие показатели по продаже товаров по видам за отчетный квартал по магазинам.

Создать следующие запросы на выборку:

1. Количество магазинов в сети
2. Количество товаров каждого вида, имеющихся в наличии.
3. Какие товары были проданы за 1.1.2017 в первом магазине.
4. Определить какой товар не купили ни разу за месяц.
5. общая стоимость проданных товаров за год
6. общая стоимость проданных товаров за отчетный квартал по магазинам
7. Перекрестный

Новый вопрос как сделать в таблице поле общая стоимость, как построить выражение которое будет обращаться к таблице товары, чтобы узнать стоимость и умножать на количество в таблице продажа ?? (запрос или таблица из выражения)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Я создал базу

```
CREATE TABLE Магазин
(
    КодМагазина  INTEGER NULL,
    название  VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    адрес  CHAR(60) NULL,
    ФИОрук  CHAR(40) NULL
)
;



ALTER TABLE Магазин
    ADD  PRIMARY KEY (КодМагазина)
;

CREATE TABLE Поступление
(
    КодПоступления  INTEGER NULL,
    количество  INTEGER NULL,
    дата  DATE NULL,
    КодМагазина  INTEGER NULL,
    КодТовара  INTEGER NULL
)
;



ALTER TABLE Поступление
    ADD  PRIMARY KEY (КодПоступления)
;



CREATE TABLE Продажа
(
    КодПродажи  INTEGER NULL,
    количество  CHAR(18) NULL,
    дата  CHAR(18) NULL,
    КодПоступления  INTEGER NULL
)
;



ALTER TABLE Продажа
    ADD  PRIMARY KEY (КодПродажи)
;



CREATE TABLE Товар
(
    КодТовара  INTEGER NULL,
    наименование  CHAR(40) NULL,
    вид  CHAR(18) NULL,
    ед  VARCHAR(10) NULL,
    стоимость  DECIMAL(19,4) NULL,
    КодМагазина  INTEGER NULL,
    КодПоступления  INTEGER NULL
)
;



ALTER TABLE Товар
    ADD  PRIMARY KEY (КодТовара)
;



ALTER TABLE Поступление
    ADD FOREIGN KEY R_1 (КодМагазина) REFERENCES Магазин(КодМагазина)
;


ALTER TABLE Поступление
    ADD FOREIGN KEY R_7 (КодТовара) REFERENCES Товар(КодТовара)
;



ALTER TABLE Продажа
    ADD FOREIGN KEY R_9 (КодПоступления) REFERENCES Поступление(КодПоступления)
;



ALTER TABLE Товар
    ADD FOREIGN KEY R_2 (КодМагазина) REFERENCES Магазин(КодМагазина)
;
```

Comment: Потому что запятая между таблицами — это CROSS JOIN, декартово произведение http://datareview.info/article/8-sposobov-obedineniya-join-tablic-v-sql-chast-1/

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT  название, наименование, количество
FROM  `магазин`, `поступление`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `товар`
ON `поступление`.`КодПоступления` = `товар`.`КодПоступления`
GROUP BY `количество` 
если так, выводит правильно но название магазина одинаковое

Comment: А почему у вас в where нет условия, которое бы как то связало магазин с товарами или поступлениями ?

Comment: я уже это выполнил

Comment: так что есть новый вопрос, как нужно было создать поле Общая стоимость